# Keep a session active on the identityServer side while using SPA

Tags: oauth, identityserver4, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.0

We have 3 applications: admin site running IdentityServer, SPA, webapi with rest services.

On the first one (with IdentityServer) we have some aditional admin ui. A requirement exists that the connected user can seamlessly go from our SPA application to this admin ui without authentication. So, from one web application to the other by redirection.

The question is how to keep both 'sessions' in sync so none expires while at least one is in use?

Example of the problem:
Settings of the apps:

1. spa_web.com - our spa application -> gets the access token valid for 1 hour and a refresh token.
2. authorityWithIdServer.com - our id provider site -> has a cookie mantaining session set to 1 hour expiry.

Steps:
1. First we go to spaWeb.com. 
2. User needs to be authenticated, so is redirected to authorityWithIdServer.com where he fills out the login form. 
3. Using authorization code flow, we are redirected back to spaWeb.com and finnaly get the access token and refresh token which are locally stored. 
4. We are using only the spa application for a few hours. Our access token is periodically renewed with the refresh token.
5. Now we decide to go to the admin ui present on the authorityWithIdServer.com. 
6. We get the login form again to sign in to that application.

Is it anyhow possible to slide the cookie of authorityWithIdServer.com while we are using spaWeb.com in order not to be forced to login again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not be using refresh tokens in client side apps. Change to authorization code and use the silent (`prompt=none` in an iframe) way of renewing the token. `oidc-client-js` implements this out of the box along with session monitoring.
2. If you do the above then since the renewal request happens in the context of the browser via the `authorize` endpoint and thus authentication with the IDP is done via cookie then any sliding logic will kick in automatically.

Also note that `identityserver4` lets you control how frequently a client must interactively authenticate via the authorize endpoint `max_age` parameter and the `UserSsoLifetime` client setting.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try the way you suggested without refresh tokens.